# JPanels do not appear on my JFrame

Tags: java, swing

```
public class Fantasy extends JFrame {
int di;
int mi;
int si;

public Fantasy() {
    setTitle("Fantasy Football");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(700,700);
    setResizable(false);

    String[] positions = {"4-4-2", "4-3-3", "3-5-2", "5-3-2", "3-4-3", "4-5-1"};

    JComboBox select = new JComboBox(positions);
    add(select, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            select.getItemAt(select.getSelectedIndex());
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\-(\\d)\\-(\\d)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(select.toString());
            m.find();
            di = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            mi = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            si = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
        }
    });

    JPanel ptch = new JPanel();
    add(ptch, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel goal = new JPanel();
    goal.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    goal.add(createGoalieHolder());

    JPanel dfnc = new JPanel();
    dfnc.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    dfnc.add(createDefenceHolder());

    JPanel midf = new JPanel();
    midf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    midf.add(createMidfHolder());

    JPanel strk = new JPanel();
    strk.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    strk.add(createStrkHolder());

    JPanel bnch = new JPanel();
    bnch.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bnch.add(createBenchHolder());

    ptch.add(goal);
    ptch.add(dfnc);
    ptch.add(midf);
    ptch.add(strk);
    add(bnch);
    setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel createGoalieHolder() {
    JPanel gh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    JTextField gk = new JTextField("Goalkeeper");
    JButton g = new JButton("+");
    gh.add(gk,g);
    return gh;
}

private JPanel createDefenceHolder() {
    JPanel dh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField df = new JTextField("Defender");
    JButton d = new JButton("+");
    for (int a = 0; a < di; a++) {
        dh.add(df,d);
    }
    return dh;
}

private JPanel createMidfHolder() {
    JPanel mh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField md = new JTextField("Midfielder");
    JButton m = new JButton("+");
    for (int b = 0; b < mi; b++) {
        mh.add(md,m);
    }
    return mh;
}


private JPanel createStrkHolder() {
    JPanel sh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField sk = new JTextField("Striker");
    JButton s = new JButton("+");
    for (int c = 0; c < si; c++) {
        sh.add(sk,s);
    }
    return sh;
}

private JPanel createBenchHolder() {
        JPanel gkh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField gkt = new JTextField("Goalkeeper");
        JButton gkb = new JButton("+");
        gkh.add(gkt,gkb);

    for(int ad = 0; ad < (5-di); ad++) {
        JPanel dfh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField dft = new JTextField("Defender");
        JButton dfb = new JButton("+");
        dfh.add(dft,dfb);
        return dfh;
    }

    for(int bd = 0; bd < (5-mi); bd++) {
        JPanel mfh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField mft = new JTextField("Midfielder");
        JButton mfb = new JButton("+");
        mfh.add(mft,mfb);
        return mfh;
    }

    for(int cd = 0; cd < (3-si); cd++) {
        JPanel sih = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField sit = new JTextField("Striker");
        JButton sib = new JButton("+");
        sih.add(sit,sib);
        return sih;
    }
    return gkh;
}
}
```

So, the createHolder methods are supposed to create JPanels with JButtons and JTextFields. Functionality will be added later. However at this point, I cannot make anything really appear on my JFrame, other than a single JTextField with the word "Defender" appear on it. I am not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

So, basically, you do this...

```
add(ptch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
add(bnch);
```

Which is pretty much the same as doing this...

```
add(ptch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
add(bnch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

or this...

```
//add(ptch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
add(bnch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

for all intense purposes.

`BorderLayout` will only manage a single component at any of the given positions, meaning that only the `bnch` is actually been laid out.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, it's difficult you know what exactly to suggest, but you could start by trying

```
add(ptch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//...
add(bnch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

which should help.

Next...

```
private JPanel createGoalieHolder() {
    JPanel gh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField gk = new JTextField("Goalkeeper");
    JButton g = new JButton("+");
    gh.add(gk, g);
    return gh;
}
```

The problem here is `gh.add(gk, g);`, the second parameter is typically the constraint property for the layout, instead, you should be doing something more like...

```
private JPanel createGoalieHolder() {
    JPanel gh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField gk = new JTextField("Goalkeeper");
    JButton g = new JButton("+");
    gh.add(gk);
    gh.add(g); 
    return gh;
}
```

and that pretty much goes for all your other create methods

You might like to spend some more time having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more details

Another problem you're going to have is...

```
private JPanel createDefenceHolder() {
    JPanel dh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    JTextField df = new JTextField("Defender");
    JButton d = new JButton("+");
    for (int a = 0; a < di; a++) {
        dh.add(df);
        dh.add(d);
    }
    return dh;
}
```

(I've corrected for the `add` method) Components can only reside within a single parent, so the above should be more like

```
private JPanel createDefenceHolder() {
    JPanel dh = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    for (int a = 0; a < di; a++) {
        JTextField df = new JTextField("Defender");
        JButton d = new JButton("+");
        dh.add(df);
        dh.add(d);
    }
    return dh;
}
```

but, when you call this method, `di` is `0` and any changes you make to `di` won't affect the UI, unless you recall this method and update the UI with the new panel

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this. I actually wanted to make separate panels for each button and textfield to be in, and then add them to the bigger Jpanels(goal,dfnc,midf,strk) and so on.

Comment: @Nazrin That's fine (and actually a reasonably good idea), and everything I've mentioned will help you along that goal